# Time Series in R - reshape?

Tags: r, sequence

I'm trying to analyse an exported .ics file from outlook.
The structure of the file is given in the following minimal example dataset

```
d1 <- structure(list(start = structure(1:3, .Label = c("01.01.2014 09:00",  "01.01.2014 18:00", "02.01.2014 08:00"), class = "factor"), end = structure(1:3, .Label = c("01.01.2014 17:00",  "01.01.2014 19:00", "02.01.2014 11:00"), class = "factor"), sth = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A",  "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("start", "end", "sth" ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

But actually I need the data in the folowing structure

```
d2 <- structure(list(time = structure(1:27, .Label = c("01.01.2014 09:00",  "01.01.2014 10:00", "01.01.2014 11:00", "01.01.2014 12:00", "01.01.2014 13:00",  "01.01.2014 14:00", "01.01.2014 15:00", "01.01.2014 16:00", "01.01.2014 17:00",  "01.01.2014 18:00", "01.01.2014 19:00", "01.01.2014 20:00", "01.01.2014 21:00",  "01.01.2014 22:00", "01.01.2014 23:00", "02.01.2014 00:00", "02.01.2014 01:00",  "02.01.2014 02:00", "02.01.2014 03:00", "02.01.2014 04:00", "02.01.2014 05:00",  "02.01.2014 06:00", "02.01.2014 07:00", "02.01.2014 08:00", "02.01.2014 09:00",  "02.01.2014 10:00", "02.01.2014 11:00"), class = "factor"), sth = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "A",  "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", "sth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -27L))
```

In words:
d1 consists of start and end time of something (sth).
I need the data in a "complete" series structure (d2) where consecutive elements are filled according to the duration of an event (sth) in d1.

I tried to play around with merging and long vs. wide...but i wasn't able to do the job...

I hope I was able to explain my problem...
Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d1)`), convert the 'start' and 'end' to POSIXct class, expand the dataset by getting the `seq` of 'start' and 'end' columns grouped by 'sth', join with the `seq` of first and last last observation of 'time', and change the `NA` elements to `''`.

```
library(data.table)
res <- setkey(setDT(d1)[, 1:2 := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct,
        format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), .SDcols=1:2][,list(time=seq(start, end,
        by='hour')) ,sth], time)[J(seq(time[1L], time[.N], by='hour'))][
        is.na(sth), sth:='']
```

if 'time' is needed in the same format as in 'd2', but I would keep it in the 'datetime' `POSIXct` class.

```
res[, time:= format(time, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')]
#   sth             time
# 1:   A 01.01.2014 09:00
# 2:   A 01.01.2014 10:00
# 3:   A 01.01.2014 11:00
# 4:   A 01.01.2014 12:00
# 5:   A 01.01.2014 13:00
# 6:   A 01.01.2014 14:00
# 7:   A 01.01.2014 15:00
# 8:   A 01.01.2014 16:00
# 9:   A 01.01.2014 17:00
#10:   B 01.01.2014 18:00
#11:   B 01.01.2014 19:00
#12:     01.01.2014 20:00
#13:     01.01.2014 21:00
#14:     01.01.2014 22:00
#15:     01.01.2014 23:00
#16:     02.01.2014 00:00
#17:     02.01.2014 01:00
#18:     02.01.2014 02:00
#19:     02.01.2014 03:00
#20:     02.01.2014 04:00
#21:     02.01.2014 05:00
#22:     02.01.2014 06:00
#23:     02.01.2014 07:00
#24:   C 02.01.2014 08:00
#25:   C 02.01.2014 09:00
#26:   C 02.01.2014 10:00
#27:   C 02.01.2014 11:00
# sth             time
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @akrun! You made my day!
I guess i now have my solution, not quite beautiful but it works for me!

```
library(data.table)
t1 <- setDT(d1)[,  seq(from=as.POSIXct(start, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), to=as.POSIXct(end, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), by='hour'), sth]
t2 <- seq(t1$V1[1], t1$V1[nrow(t1)], by="hour")
t1 <- as.data.frame(t1)
t2 <- data.frame(t2)
names(t2) <- "time"
names(t1) <- c("sth", "time")
merge(t2, t1, by="time", all=T)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What am I doing wrong..? It throws me an error: `Error in seq.POSIXt(time[1L], time[.N], by = "hour") : 
  'to' must be of length 1`

Comment: I used data.table_1.9.5, and I got the result as shown in 'd2'.  Which version of data.table are you using?

Comment: using yours. I copied your code from above and run it on the data given above.

Comment: data.table_1.9.2. Let me update it and test it again.

Comment: It is a bit old.  I don't know whether `setDT` works on that.  I updated the post with the output I got

Comment: running into problems updating the package... give me a minute to try again. but i'm acctually sure you solution works fine and it's definitely more elegant and faster then mine!

Comment: Make sure that you have the most recent version of R.  I use R 3.2.0.  If your version is really old, it may encounter some problems in updating, so I would first upgrade the R

Comment: Works perfect with newest version of R and data.table! Thanx!!

Comment: Hi @akrun Unfortunatelly i ran into a problem since the actual names of the events (i.e. "sth") aren't unique over the whole dataset. The code then gives me the following error: `Error in seq.POSIXt(start, end, by = "hour") : 'from' must be of length 1`

Comment: Could you post an example data that reproduce the problem as a new post?

Comment: `d1 <- structure(list(start = structure(1:4, .Label = c("01.01.2014 09:00", "01.01.2014 18:00", "02.01.2014 08:00", "02.01.2014 11:00"), class = "factor"), end = structure(1:4, .Label = c("01.01.2014 17:00", "01.01.2014 19:00", "02.01.2014 11:00", "02.01.2014 12:00"), class = "factor"), sth = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("start", "end", "sth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))`

Comment: Or can you try with `list(time=seq(start, end,
        by='hour')) ,by= 1:nrow(DT)]`

Comment: Try `setkey(setDT(d1)[, 1:2 := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), .SDcols=1:2][, list(time=seq(start, end, by='hour')), by=list(sth, Row=1:nrow(d1))], time)[J(seq(time[1L],time[.N], by='hour'))][is.na(sth), sth:=''][, Row:=NULL]`

Comment: gives me this: `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 29 rows; more than 28 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.`

Comment: I commented just before your comment.  Try with that code

Comment: Using the updated code didn't gave any error for me.

Comment: Did you got the error in the example `d1` you posted now (which I can't reproduce) or in the original dataset?

Comment: I get the error in the **new d1**... can i show the "new" d1 other than dput so it's possible to  reproduce it? The new d1 acctually just includes another row containing the following observation :  4 `02.01.2014 11:00 02.01.2014 12:00   A`

Comment: The dput gives the correct structure, so I don't know how you are getting an error while I am not